# Lost/Missing Folders

Tags: directory

I've been running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop for a few weeks. Today I tried to create several new folders in:

`Home/documents/New Folder_A/New Folder_B`.

I created the folders, added some documents, and navigated out of the `Home` folder. When I went back in to access my new folders, they were gone along with the documents I added.

I used the search function but could not find the new folders. I tried creating new ones with the same name as previously used and a warning came up stating a folder with that name was already in use. However they are nowhere to be found.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are those spaces part of the directory names?

Comment: Did you create them from command line or GUI?

Comment: I just used the folder names "New Folder_A, _B" as examples. I just created the folders by right clicking and using the drop down selection "New Folder". I'm new to Linux and this is the method I used for my windows computer. Should I be using a different method to create folders?

Comment: Did you create the folders using the `-p` option like this `mkdir -p /Home/documents/New Folder_A/New Folder_B` or if in _document directory already_ like this `mkdir -p New Folder_A/New Folder_B`. And a full listing of the steps would help.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal navigate to `/home/$USER/Documents/` and type :

`ls -la`

to see if you can spot those missing folder(s).

To navigate to the folder names `/home/$USER/Documents/New Folder_A/New Folder_B` type the following in the terminal:

`cd "/home/$USER/Documents/New Folder_A/New Folder_B"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I performed the above in the terminal. /home/$USER/Documents/New Folder_A/New Folder_B.  With the following response: New Folder_B is a directory. I assume that means my folder is there. The problem is that I can's see the icon. I tried again to create a new "New Folder_B and a message box appeared saying there was already a folder with that name. Still confused.

Comment: Further. Using the Search tool I can locate "New Folder_A". A right click on it shows there are 8 items (One of which should be "New Folder_B"). However when I open it, I can only see 3 documents, but no folders.